# Code Optimization: Computation in Torch.Tensor

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I am currently implementing a function to compute Custom Cross Entropy Loss.
The definition of the function is a following image.

[image: cite from "Deep Ordinal Regression Network for Monocular Depth Estimation", Huan Fu et al. CVPR 2018]

my codes are as following,

```
output = output.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
target = target.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)

batch, height, width, channel = output.size()

total_loss = 0.
for b in range(batch): # for each batch
    o = output[b]
    t = target[b]
    loss = 0.
    for w in range(width):
        for h in range(height): # for every pixel([h,w]) in the image
            sid_t = t[h][w][0]
            sid_o_candi = o[h][w]
            part1 = 0. # to store the first sigma 
            part2 = 0. # to store the second sigma

            for k in range(0, sid_t):
                p = torch.sum(sid_o_candi[k:]) # to get Pk(w,h)
                part1 += torch.log(p + 1e-12).item()

            for k in range(sid_t, intervals):
                p = torch.sum(sid_o_candi[k:]) # to get Pk(w,h)
                part2 += torch.log(1-p + 1e-12).item()

            loss += part1 + part2

    loss /= width * height * (-1)
    total_loss += loss
total_loss /= batch
return torch.tensor(total_loss, dtype=torch.float32)
```

I am wondering is there any optimization could be done with these code.

Comment: Your Question is more suitable for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure `sid_t = t[h][w][0]` is the same for every pixel or not. If so, you can get rid of all `for loop` which boost the speed of computing loss.

> Don't use `.item()` because it will return a Python value which loses the `grad_fn` track. Then you can't use `loss.backward()` to compute the gradients.

If `sid_t = t[h][w][0]` is not the same, here is some modification to help you get rid of at least 1 `for-loop`:

```py
batch, height, width, channel = output.size()

total_loss = 0.
for b in range(batch): # for each batch
    o = output[b]
    t = target[b]
    loss = 0.
    for w in range(width):
        for h in range(height): # for every pixel([h,w]) in the image
            sid_t = t[h][w][0]
            sid_o_candi = o[h][w]
            part1 = 0. # to store the first sigma 
            part2 = 0. # to store the second sigma

            sid1_cumsum = sid_o_candi[:sid_t].flip(dim=(0,)).cumsum(dim=0).flip(dims=(0,)) 
            part1 = torch.sum(torch.log(sid1_cumsum + 1e-12))

            sid2_cumsum = sid_o_candi[sid_t:intervals].flip(dim=(0,)).cumsum(dim=0).flip(dims=(0,)) 
            part2 = torch.sum(torch.log(1 - sid2_cumsum + 1e-12))

            loss += part1 + part2

    loss /= width * height * (-1)
    total_loss += loss
total_loss /= batch
return torch.tensor(total_loss, dtype=torch.float32)
```

How it works:

```py
x = torch.arange(10); 
print(x)

x_flip = x.flip(dims=(0,)); 
print(x_flip)

x_inverse_cumsum = x_flip.cumsum(dim=0).flip(dims=(0,))
print(x_inverse_cumsum)

# output
tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
tensor([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
tensor([45, 45, 44, 42, 39, 35, 30, 24, 17,  9])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a typo in this statement "part2 = torch.sum(torch.(torch.log(1 - sid2_cumsum + 1e-12)))", since my interpreter reports errors?